# Unable to start ActiveMQ "Classic" server - Could not load class: org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand

Tags: java, activemq-classic, classpath

I just downloaded and unzipped the latest version of  ActiveMQ "Classic" (apache-activemq-5.17.2) from [this link](https://activemq.apache.org/components/classic/download/) into a folder named:

```
C:\executables\apache-activemq
```

However, when I run the following command:

```
C:\executables\apache-activemq>bin\activemq start
```

It fails on the following message:

```
Could not load class: org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand
```

How can I get this up and running?

Here's the full output:

```
Java Runtime: Azul Systems, Inc. 11.0.14.1 C:\Program Files\Zulu\zulu-11
  Heap sizes: current=1048576k  free=1040894k  max=1048576k
    JVM args: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Xms1G -Xmx1G -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties -Djava.security.auth.login.config=C:\executables\apache-activemq\\conf\login.config -Dactivemq.classpath=C:\executables\apache-activemq\\conf;C:\executables\apache-activemq\/conf;C:\executables\apache-activemq\/conf; -Dactivemq.home=C:\executables\apache-activemq" -Dactivemq.base=C:\executables\apache-activemq" -Dactivemq.conf=C:\executables\apache-activemq\\conf -Dactivemq.data=C:\executables\apache-activemq\\data -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\executables\apache-activemq\\data\tmp
Extensions classpath:
  [C:\executables\apache-activemq" -Dactivemq.base=C:\executables\apache-activemq"\lib,C:\executables\apache-activemq" -Dactivemq.base=C:\executables\apache-activemq"\lib\camel,C:\executables\apache-activemq" -Dactivemq.base=C:\executables\apache-activemq"\lib\optional,C:\executables\apache-activemq" -Dactivemq.base=C:\executables\apache-activemq"\lib\web,C:\executables\apache-activemq" -Dactivemq.base=C:\executables\apache-activemq"\lib\extra]
ACTIVEMQ_HOME: C:\executables\apache-activemq" -Dactivemq.base=C:\executables\apache-activemq"
ACTIVEMQ_BASE: C:\executables\apache-activemq" -Dactivemq.base=C:\executables\apache-activemq"
ACTIVEMQ_CONF: C:\executables\apache-activemq\conf
ACTIVEMQ_DATA: C:\executables\apache-activemq\data
Could not load class: org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand
Class loader setup:
jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$PlatformClassLoader
  jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader
    java.net.URLClassLoader {
      file:/C:/executables/apache-activemq/conf/
    }
```

Comment: I just did this on a fresh Windows 10 VM, and I didn't get that error (although I did hit [AMQ-8596](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-8596)). I am using Oracle's Java 17 distribution rather than Azul's, though. I'm guessing this is some kind of environmental issue on your end.

Comment: Actually, I got the exact same error you got (AMQ-8596) the first time I tried. I added ACTIVEMQ_HOME to the environment variables, then got the error I posted about. When I got rid of ACTIVEMQ_HOME, I still get the error error I posted about (I started a new command line). 

I originally was going to use RabbitMQ, which I was able to get running, but then was told to use ActiveMQ because it's used in one of our other products. I will try that version and see if it works. I'll post the version here if it does.

Comment: Thanks for the editing my post to "ActiveMQ Classic". That made me realize there is a later version of ActiveMQ (Artemis), which I hadn't realized at first. Seeing as it is a later release, I'll probably go with that.